# Why does sprintf add an 'H' at the end?

Tags: c, printf

I tried to use sprintf to add 143.5 to s, but when I printed s, there was an extra H behind it.

Can someone explain why? I'm just curious.

**Thanks!**

(Also sorry for my bad English)

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
   char s[5 + 1];
   sprintf(s, "%5.1f", 143.5);

   for (int i = 0; i <= strlen(s) + 1; i++)
   {
       printf("%c", s[i]);
   }
   printf("\n");

   return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
143.5H
```

Comment: why is your `for` condition set to `strlen(...) + 1` ? did you display that value ?

Comment: This program is small enough that you can step through every line in the debugger. Step through the code, paying close attention to your `for` loop and the value of `i` and `s[i]`.

Comment: (1) You're walking past the end of the array.  The last element has index `strlen(s) - 1`.  The null character has index `strlen(s)`.  You're going up to `strlen(s) + 1`, which is past the null character, so of course you're getting garbage.  (2) It makes no sense to use `strlen` at all in the loop test.  Just use `s[i] != '\0'`.  (3) Even if it did make sense to use `strlen` in the loop test, you would compute it once, before entering the loop, rather than every single time though the loop (just as a human would do).  Don't needlessly do more work than the problem requires.

Comment: If `l = strlen(s)` then s[0], s[1],..., s[l-1] are the characters of the string. s[l] should be the null '\0', and s[l+1] is an undefined  value.

Comment: ryker  sun, Try `printf("%c", s[i]);` --> `printf("(%d %d %c)\n", i, s[i], s[i]);` to see why code fails.

Comment: The buffer `s` is too small; although you get away with it for this exact value, other float values will write out of bounds

Comment: Thanks for all the answers above, I already understand, thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are going past the array's range, you are likely accessing old or random data in memory. As a result you print something unintended. This is so-called undefined behavior.

You'll want to loop from `0` to `< strlen(...)`. Doing `<=` and `+1` makes it go 2 extra iterations, causing you to print a null `\0` and this `H` character from raw memory.

Another solution (as mentioned by @Tom_Karzes) is to use `s[i] != '\0'` as the loop's exit test, assuming your string is correctly null-terminated.

Comment: As the buffer length is known it may be valuable to check _both_ for null character and the end of the buffer. `s[i] != '\0' && i < buffer_len`